# Why when image rendering object did not show up but in 3d rendering show up

Tags: rendering, image, uv-image-editor

I am new to Blender. I try to make donuts, but my object does not appear when I start rendering. So how to solve this? Because in-camera perspective, the object appears

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe check the render visibility settings in the Outliner window?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I have solved the problem from what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot looks like your model is incredibly small (from the zoomed in grid)
Check your model dimensions (via the inspector panel, accessible via the <kbd>N</kbd> key shortcut) and scale up the size of your model to something more realistic.

I’m guessing you’re running into clipping issues with your camera's minimum frustum distance.

Also double check that your camera is the active camera.

Answer (score 0):

Check the render visibility settings of your objects in the *Outliner* window:

[image]